# Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, utf-8

I'm wondering how i would go about fixing this error:

`Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding`

Located here:
http://xml.skiddlecdn.co.uk/affiliates/all.xml

The code im using looks like this:

```
skiddlexml = 'http://xml.skiddlecdn.co.uk/affiliates/all.xml'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(skiddlexml))

@ticket_json = []
doc.css('event#' + params[:id]).css('ticket').each do |node|
  children = node.children
  @ticket_json << {
    'name' => children.css('name').inner_text,
    'faceValue' => children.css('faceValue').inner_text,
    'bookingFee' => children.css('bookingFee').inner_text,
    'quantity' => children.css('quantity').inner_text,
    'status' => children.css('status').inner_text
  }
end

doc.css('event#' + params[:id]).each do |node|
  @skiddle_url = node['link'].chomp('?sktag=XXX') + '?sktag=13942'
end
respond_to do |format|
   format.json  { render :json => {:tickets => @ticket_json, :skiddle_url => @skiddle_url } }
end
```

I'm wondering if theres a way of decoding it and reencoding it so the code is still the same?

Sam

**Edit**

as you can see in the events controller it currently uses a params id to search the XML file,

If we take the id `12987613` it can't fine it, However sublime shows the id showing on line 137631

Answer (score 0):

Well, the initial problem is just the XML file is wrong anyway, so ideally you should get them to fix the file.

e.g. tryiong to display in Chrome gives errors:

> ### This page contains the following errors:
>
> error on line 56849 at column 27: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
> Bytes: 0x1E 0x63 0x20 0x61
>
> ### Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

But the XML file is claiming UTF-8:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

However, Nokogiri actually can load that by default (not investigated exactly what happens to those invalid bytes), since its default mode is to recover (see http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html)

> `RECOVER` - Attempt to recover from errors. Recommended for parsing malformed or invalid documents. **This is set by default!**

But again it is reporting errors due to the XML document itself.

```
doc.errors
[#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: 56849:123: FATAL: CData section not finished
A unique  and rare opportunity to experience, the >,
#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: 56849:123: FATAL: PCDATA invalid Char value 30>,
#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: 56849:158: FATAL: Sequence ']]>' not allowed in content>,
#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: 56849:158: FATAL: Sequence ']]>' not allowed in content>,
#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: 56849:158: FATAL: internal error: detected an error in element content
```

You could load and then save the file again, but at least you will likely loose some of the data being complained about. Better to fix whatever is creating that file, or if its done somewhat manually, to manually inspect the location of those syntax errors, see if you can determine what is expected and correct them.

Comment: Unfortunately the provider, isn't replying to my emails (not fallen out with them, just hasn't ever responded to emails)  What would be the best way to resolve this locally is possible (bare in mind i would normally call this xml at least once a day)

Comment: Well see what issues you have with Nokogiri doing its best, if its just loosing a bit of corrupted text content, maybe that is OK? If you have to manually fix it but the broken records are fairly static (same every time/day) then you could use like a diff/patch to fix it before parsing, depends exactly how the XML is getting broken.

Comment: From what i can see anythign lower in the file isn't being read,  however when you bring it down it does,. Let me add an edit and you can see the steps i have taken